# Visual Studio Code: How to stop showing weird characters while saving file

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Whenever I am trying click <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save files in Mac Visual Studio Code. It shows weird characters, how can I disable this?

Comment: Those "weird characters" are possible alternate international matches to the letter 's'. Perhaps that will give you clue as to what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS, if you hold a key while entering text a popup is shown with the various accented forms of the character.

To disable this, you may want to run this command in terminal:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

You'll need to logout and login in order to changes take effect.

If you want to restore the initial behaviour, just run:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

And again you'll need to logout and login.